# Avoiding the endless loop in JSP servlet mapping

Tags: java, jsp, rest, servlets, restful-url

I've got this issue, recently I read about the [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) arquitecture and it makes a perfect sense, so I'd like to achieve a RESTful web application.

Now, I'm following the [Front Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) that means that all of the URL mappings go to the `controller.java` servlet, I map the by specific URLs, not by using the `/*` wildcard,
the controller implements the four HTTP methods `POST`,`GET`,`PUT`,`DELETE`, each method calls the controllers `service` method and there I determine based on the `HttpServletRequest` and `pathInfo` the action to execute.
Controller.java

```
 @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        IAction action;
        View view;
        try {
            action = ActionFactory.produceAction(req);
            view = action.execute(req, resp);
            switch (view.getDispatchMethod()) {
                case REDIRECT:
                    resp.sendRedirect(resp.encodeURL(view.getResource()));
                    break;
                case FORWARD:
                    req.getRequestDispatcher(view.getResource()).forward(req, resp);
                    break;
                case INCLUDE:
                    req.getRequestDispatcher(view.getResource()).include(req,resp);
                    break;
                default:
            }
        } catch (ActionFailedException uae) {
            req.setAttribute("ActionName", "Action");
            req.setAttribute("FailCause", uae.getMessage());
            req.getRequestDispatcher(VIEW_FAIL.getResource()).forward(req, resp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.service(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.service(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.service(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.service(req, resp);
    }
```

I've run into a particular issue when loading a specific order by the URI `/orders/*`, it is mapped to the controller servlet, the the action is executed and I load the appropriate order the action returns a `View.java` class

```
//ommited accessors and mutators for brevety.
public class View {
public enum DispatchMethod {
        INCLUDE, FORWARD, REDIRECT
    }

    private DispatchMethod dispatchMethod;
    private String resource;

    public View(DispatchMethod dispatchMethod, String resource) {
        this.dispatchMethod = dispatchMethod;
        this.resource = resource;
    }
}
```

Then the request is dispatched according to the `getDispatchMethod()` of the returned view.

Now, here is where the loop gets triggered, I use the following URL, `myapp/orders/78965` `/orders/*` gets mapped to `controller.java` the appropriate action is executed and the correct order is found by the `pathInfo()` the returned view is `new View(View.DispatchMethod.FORWARD,"order_details.jsp")` the problem is that with the three available dispatch methods `REDIRECT,FORWARD and INCLUDE` a request is re-triggered on the URL and so on and on and on I never reach the `order_details.jsp` that renders the data.

So, how would you avoid the looping, as I'd like to preserve the URI displaying the order number I use the forward method, also, I'd like to do it using servlets, I've heard of the UrlRewriteFilter maybe in the future, but right now, how would it be done using "Plain Vanilla" since I'm using the Front Controller pattern, will it be necessary to add an additional servlet in the `/orders/` URI ?

Any help or insights is truly appreciated.

---

**EDIT 1:**

Pasted the source code of the controller, a very basic one, I have my suspicions that the way the `service` method calls all of the overriden `do[Method]` of the servlet is triggering the loop and that it may be solved by splittig them.

Comment: You're talking about servlets, but the symptoms indicate that you're using a filter which hooks on all the three dispatch methods instead of (default) `REQUEST`. Or am I totally misunderstanding you?

Comment: The only filter I use is an Authentication filter, which is indee applied using `/*` but I don't see how that triggers the request aover and over as it only checks if the user is logged in.

Comment: Well.. I'd love to help, but you really have to display a minimum necessary code snippet which shows just the raw Servlet API classes/methods which reproduces this exact problem, instead of your private/homegrown API which nobody else has knowledge about. By the way, is this just a private learning exercise? If so, then nevermind me and just go ahead, if not then I recommend to adopt an existing API instead of homegrowing one, such as the wonderful JAX-RS API. It's built on top of Servlet API as well. See also http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: Hi, @BalusC, thank you for your reply, yes it is a learning exercise.

Comment: To be sure, do the `view.getResource()` during forward/include return an URL which matches the URL pattern of this servlet? It shouldn't. You'd usually like to have those JSP resources in `/WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Generally the resource is prefixed with the `"/WEB-INF/"` string if the `jsp` is in the `/WEB-INF` folder

Answer (score 2):

Implementing a RESTful HTTP interface in Java is a lot easier using a JAX-RS implementation like [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) or [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/).

Using a Front Controller to dispatch requests to the right resource is a good approach, it's exactly the approach taken by these JAX-RS frameworks. I fear you may be re-inventing the wheel here by writing a bespoke URL parsing and dispatching mechanism when this can be taken off-the-shelf.

JAX-RS is a lightweight way to expose resources. By using a couple of simple annotations you can expose a REST interface without any plumbing required. For example:

```
public class Order {

    @GET
    @Path("/orders/{orderId}")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public void getOrder(@Context HttpServletResponse response,
                         @Context HttpServletRequest request,
                         @PathParam("orderId") String orderId) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // ... create view and add to request here

        request.getRequestDispatcher("orders.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

You can see how simple it is to attach this class to a URL path (using the `@Path` annotation), and how easily you can parse values from the URL using `@PathParam`. Since you get all the plumbing/dispatching/parsing off-the-shelf, you can concentrate on the bits of your app that are specific to your domain (such as what an order contains).

Comment: Is this using the Jersey implementation or just the JAX-RS API, as all of my searches for JAX-RS point to Jersey, maybe you can clear some points of it, is the JAX-RS a standalone or do I have to use the Jersey implementation?.

Comment: JAX-RS is a specification, part of JEE. You can think of JAX-RS as a set of interfaces/annotations with no implementation. To create an application, you need to choose an implementation of JAX-RS. RESTEasy is one implementation (owned by JBoss), Jersey is another (Jersey is the reference implementation, available on java.net). There are also other, less popular implementations like Apache CXF and Restlet. Which container are you deploying to (and which version)? Your container may already include a JAX-RS implementation you can use.

Comment: I'm deploying to apache-tomcat 6.0.26, I've read some comparisons, while I hate the Jersey name, it seems that it is much simpler than RESTlet (which has a cool name), care to share any experiences?

Comment: I'd recommend [RESTEasy 2.1.0.GA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resteasy/files/Resteasy%20JAX-RS/2.1.0.GA/). It's very easy to configure, particularly in a simple servlet container like tomcat. It's also mature and has many integration points. I've only used the client API of Jersey (which is excellent) but I imagine it is much the same. Restlet has been around for a long time, it had its own alternative approach (non-JAX-RS) to implementing REST resources, which I have used. More recently it has added a JAX-RS compliant implementation, but I think the library in general is showing its age.

Comment: @Triz: Choosing an implementation based on just the name is insane. Choose it based on the features it provides and the degree of maintenance/support from the development team and the community.

Comment: LOL, Yeah I know its insane its just that some names are just bad jeje, I just said it as a side comment.

Comment: @Triztian, if it was helpful, do you mind showing this answer some love?